# How to create a Nagios monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, nagios

How to create a Nagios monitor that triggers an alarm when the load on my machine is > 0.5. I manage to install and configure Nagios on Ubuntu 16.04 and now i'm stuck on this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which machine? Assuming the machine you're referring to is the same machine that Nagios is installed on, then this is super easy!

First, you'll need to define a command in your commands config file (**NOTE:** in all actuality this is probably already defined - you can double check by doing a `grep "check_local_load"` in your Nagios config directory):

```
define command {
       command_name                             check_local_load
       command_line                             $USER1$/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
}
```

And then, in your services config file, you'll want to define the following service (**NOTE:** again, this actually probably already defined - you'll just need to tweak the `check_command` line to adjust the warning and critical arguments) (and since you didn't specify *which* load, we'll just assume you mean all of them [1min, 5min, 15min]):

```
define service {
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Current Load
        use                             local-service
        check_command                   check_local_load!0.5,0.5,0.5!0.5,0.5,0.5
        register                        1
        }
```

You're also going to have to make sure that you set up your notifications properly. If the above didn't help, then I would sincerely suggest reading the handbook available here: (I think the packages for Ubuntu are still Core 3? Unfortunately, we aren't the packagers or maintainers so I'm not particularly sure)

[Nagios Core 3 Documentation, Table of Contents](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/toc.html)

Hope this helps!